# RxJava error handling withought swallowing the error

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

I'm a little bit new to RxJava. I am trying to emit another item if onError() get called without losing the error(I still want onError() to be called on the observer). but when I'm implementing each of the error handling methods declared in the [docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators) the error being swallowed and on error isn't being called. any solutions?

edit:
that's what I've tried to do yesterday -

```
@Override
public Observable<ArrayList<Address>> getAirports() {
    return new Observable<ArrayList<AirportPOJO>>() {
        @Override
        protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super ArrayList<AirportPOJO>> observer) {
            try {
                // get airports from api list and map it
                ArrayList<AirportPOJO> airportsList = apiDb.getAirportsList(POJOHelper.toPOJO(AppCredentialManager.getCredentials()));
                observer.onNext(airportsList);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                observer.onError(handleException(e));
            }
        }
    }.map(AirportsMappers.getAirportsPojoToDomainAirportsMapper()).doOnNext(new Consumer<ArrayList<Address>>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(ArrayList<Address> airportsList) throws Exception {
            // if airports loaded from api - save them to local db
            if (airportsList != null) {
                try {
                    localDb.saveAirportList(AirportsMappers.getAirportsToLocalDbAirportsMapper().apply(airportsList));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).onErrorResumeNext(new Function<Throwable, ObservableSource<? extends ArrayList<Address>>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<? extends ArrayList<Address>> apply(final Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
            // load the local airports - 
            ArrayList<LocalDbAirportEntity> localAirportsEntities = localDb.getAirports();
            // map
            ArrayList<Address> airports = AirportsMappers.getLocalDbAirportsToAirportsMapper().apply(localAirportsEntities);
            // return the concat observable with the error
            return Observable.just(airports).concatWith(Observable.
                    <ArrayList<Address>>error(new Callable<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public Throwable call() throws Exception {
                            return throwable;
                        }
                    }));
        }
    });
}
```

today I tought I might doing it wrong and tried -

```
@Override
public Observable<ArrayList<Address>> getAirports() {
    ArrayList<Observable<ArrayList<Address>>> observables = new ArrayList<>();
    observables.add(apiDb.getAirportsList(POJOHelper.toPOJO(AppCredentialManager.getCredentials())).map(AirportsMappers.getAirportsPojoToDomainAirportsMapper()));
    observables.add(localDb.getAirports().map(AirportsMappers.getLocalDbAirportsToAirportsMapper()));
    Observable<ArrayList<Address>> concatenatedObservable = Observable.concatDelayError(observables);
    return concatenatedObservable;
}
```

but I've got the same result. the onNext() called with the data of the second observable and the onError() not being called afterwards.

Comment: Why are you doing `new Observable`? Also you implemented it incorreclty. Why not use `Observable.fromCallable` there? Do you have `observeOn` anywhere else? Use [this](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#observeOn-io.reactivex.Scheduler-boolean-) overload to prevent an error cutting ahead. Why do you use the `error(Callable)` overload instead of the direct overload I suggested?

Comment: couldn't found the overload you suggested. I have observeOn() in my tranformer so I tried downstream.observeOn(scheduler,true) but it's still swallowing the error.

Comment: Then it's time to add `doOnNext` and `doOnError` operators all around to see where events disappear.

Comment: Solved by finding the overload you suggested initially and add dowstream.observeOn(scheduler,true). Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resume with the desired value concatenated with the original error:

```java
source.onErrorResumeNext(error ->
    Observable.just(item).concatWith(Observable.<ItemType>error(error))
);
```

Comment: tried and it moves directly to onErorr withought getting the item in onNext()

Comment: Please post the entire flow you are having trouble with.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this flow -  fetch data from network -> if not successful -> emit the error -> fetch data from local storage -> emit the local storage data. I need to be able to call observer.onError() and afterwards observer.onNext()

Comment: Please provide the **code** you tried to insert the example into.

Comment: Not at the office right now, But I would rather you provide me the way for the solution rather than solve the exact problem. I want to understand better the RxJava concepts so the next time I would be able to solve my problems by myself...

Comment: The example I gave should work, unless you forgot to mention something important, hence seeing your code would help me help you help us all.